# Replacing a cell with error with zeroe using using VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that runs over a specific range. I want it to  replace an error value, more specifically an #NA value, with zero and add 1 to non-error cells.

This is my code:

```
Sub TestSub_()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim rng_ As range

    Set rng_ = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("testrange")

    i = 0
    j = 0

    While rng_(i + 1, j + 1) <> ""
        While rng_(i + 1, j + 1) <> ""
            If WorksheetFunction.IsErr(rng_(i + 1, j + 1)) Then
                rng_(i + 1, j + 1).ClearContents
                rng_(i+1,j+1) = 0
                'enter code here
            Else
                rng_(i + 1, j + 1) = rng_(i + 1, j + 1) + 1
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Wend
        j = 0
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

I run into an "Error 13: Type mismatch" error when I run the macro. However, I don't see any mismatches in data types.

Comment: Why not just use something like `For each Cell in MyRange' loop, where `MyRange` is declared before entering your loop?

Comment: Rng_ is already set then you're trying to append a new range to it each time. `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("testrange")(i + 1, j+ 1)` is not a valid range.

Comment: `#N/A` is an `Error` value, of type `Error`. Error values can't be compared to strings, numbers, or anything - hence "type mismatch". Use `IsError` to test whether a cell contains any error, or if you need to specifically handle `#N/A`, then test for it with `If [the range value] = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then`

Answer (score 1):

This can be reduced to the below code (assuming you want to check every cell in some predetermined range named `testrange`)

**Also, change** `IsErr` **to** `IsError`**:**

`IsErr` will capture all errors EXCEPT `#N/A`
`IsError` will capture all errors

Thus, your `Error 13: Type Mismatch` was likely due to feeding a `#N/A` or `<> ""` into the `IsErr` function

```
Sub TestSub_()
Dim rng_ As Range
Dim mycell As Range
Set rng_ = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("testrange")

For Each mycell In rng_
    If IsError(mycell) Then
        mycell.Value = 0
    Else
        mycell = mycell.Value + 1
    End If
Next mycell

End Sub
```

Comment: This will need to be adjusted if your range is not strictly limited to numbers and `#N/A`

Comment: No need for `WorksheetFunction.IsError` to get involved, there's a VBA-native `IsError` function for this.

Comment: This answer is correct so I'm not going to post another, but consider completing it with information from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842208/replacing-a-cell-with-error-with-zeroe-using-using-vba-macro#comment88688783_50842208) for a more thorough explanation and fine-tuned solution (although, handling `IsError` is probably a better idea than only handling `#N/A`).

Comment: Actually the type mismatch was more likely occurring on `rng_(i + 1, j + 1) <> ""`, where `<> ""` isn't a legal comparison against an `Error` value.